# Rails postgresql how to set transaction isolation level to serializable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, transactions, callback

I have a Comment model which belongs_to a Topic model. On the Comment model, I have a before_create callback

```
def on_create
  Topic.transaction(:require_new => true) do
    Topic.connection.execute('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE')
    self.topic.increment!(:comment_counter) if conditions
  end
end
```

The problem is that I get a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query`.

Is there another way to set the transaction isolation level?

Comment: Can you set it before starting the transaction?

Comment: That was my question, actually - how to set the isolation level before the whole model save transaction starts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PostgreSQL requires `SET TRANSACTION` statements to be executed after a transaction starts and before any DML (SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, etc.) statement. From the documentation, it looks like all that stuff will have to be done through the connection object, not the transaction object. Something like (untested)

```
Topic.connection.begin_db_transaction
  Topic.connection.execute('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE')
  # Other things go here. I'd test with another literal SQL statement to make
  # sure it works like I'd hope it does. Then possibly try rewriting in Rails.
Topic.connection.commit_db_transaction
```

I *really* hope I'm wrong about that.

One distasteful alternative is to change the default isolation level for all transactions on the PostgreSQL server. (Search http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html for "default_transaction_isolation ".) But that feels like using a cannon to kill a fly.

Comment: The code would work in isolation, but the main problem is that this Topic transaction is wrapped in another transaction. Apparently, it's not possible to use nested transactions with different isolation levels, so I would need a way to make the first transaction serializable - and I would not like to make any transactions on the Comment model serializable.

Comment: @eugen: To nest a transaction with a different isolation level is a logical paradox. This cannot be done.

Comment: @Catcall, thank you - your comments actually pointed me to another way to solve the problem, I'm going to accept the answer as is.

Comment: @Catcall: By using the after_commit callback - this one runs after the original transaction is committed, so it can run in its own transaction.

Comment: @eugen: So you basically unnested the transactions?

Comment: @Catcall: Indeed, I had to unnest the transactions. Testing is also a bit more difficult (I had to disable the transactional fixtures), but it seems to work this way.

Comment: @eugen: Is the best way to unnest your transactions to run one in the after_commit callback of the other?

Comment: @Catcall: It's one solution. I'm not sure it's the best, but it works for now.

Answer (score 10):

As of Rails 4, [`#transaction` provides an `:isolation` option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-transaction):

> If your database supports setting the isolation level for a transaction, you can set it like so:
>
> ```
> Post.transaction(isolation: :serializable) do
>   # ...
> end
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You may find transaction_isolation gem helpful: https://github.com/qertoip/transaction_isolation