# Set PostgreSQL transaction isolation persistently

Tags: postgresql, serialization, persistence, transaction-isolation, server-variables

I'd like to persistently set the transaction isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` for all future sessions, but I can see only see [a way to do it at the session](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-set-transaction.html) only.

If this is possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916926/1382306) has the solution.

The variable is `default_transaction_isolation`.

Comment: Do be aware that this may surprise applications that are not expecting serialization failure rollbacks - though most apps that support multiple DBs should be written to cope, as some DBs default to serializable.

Comment: @CraigRinger Indeed!  In my case, I need perfect data at high speeds and don't care about failed writes as it can be easily remedied by later attempts, a special case.