# How to set a Ruby on Rails 4+ app's default db isolation level

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I want to make my application [serialize](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html) every transaction by default. I'd then relax isolation based on performance measurements and knowing what data particular actions/transactions use and change.

I doubt serializable by default would get into the framework, as it'd slow things down and be difficult to explain. But I don't want to deal with db corruption, and do want internally consistent aggregate calculations.

For case-by-case isolation levels there is [Rails postgresql how to set transaction isolation level to serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915209/rails-postgresql-how-to-set-transaction-isolation-level-to-serializable) but I think this approach is wrong for the same reasons html-escaping to protect against xss were wrong and were dropped: whitelisting is safer than blacklisting.

Has anyone done this already?
Where would be a good place to hook into rails to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the isolation level of all my rails transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431219/how-do-i-set-the-isolation-level-of-all-my-rails-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this the default, then I suggest setting it in your MySQL config. The setting is described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_transaction-isolation

```
[mysqld]
default-character-set = utf8
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
default-table-type = InnoDB
transaction-isolation = SERIALIZABLE
```

For PostgreSQL the setting is called [default_transaction_isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TRANSACTION-ISOLATION). You can set this in [postgresql.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE).

Comment: Can that be set on the database rather than the whole DBMS? It doesn't fit our use-case as we're on a hosted service without access to config files but interesting nevertheless.

Comment: For MySQL you can use `SET TRANSACTION`. You could try `SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION`, but I'm not sure if that will work if you have only restricted database access. However, you could also call `SET SESSION TRANSACTION` as the very first SQL statement, that should do the trick. I'm not totally sure how, but you could probably hook into something that runs after Rails creates a new database connection.